# Overwrite an element's style multiple times in loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-grid

I have a simple menu that's currently using CSS Grid that I want to be animated. However, `grid-template-columns` can't be smoothly animated. I am now doing the menu completely different, but in my search for a solution I came across something that I can't quite figure out. My first idea, although it might not a good idea at all and probably isn't a suitable alternative for keyframe animations, was to update styles in a while loop to animate the increasing size of the item. It doesn't work.

The relevant JS:

```
    $('#select-oak').hover(function () {
            let start = new Date().getTime();
            let elapsed = 0;

            while (elapsed <= 1000) {
                elapsed = new Date().getTime() - start;
                let val = elapsed / 1000;

                if (elapsed % 100 === 0) {
                    $('.selector-block').css('grid-template-columns', `${1.0 + val}fr 1fr 1fr 1fr`);
                    console.log(1 + val);
                    console.log(elapsed);
                }
            }
        }
```

The CSS:

```
.selector-block {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: -32.5vh;
    background-color: white;
    gap: 5px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 90vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    clip-path: polygon(0 36%, 100% 0, 100% 60%, 0% 100%);
    z-index: 3;
}

#select-oak {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(94, 80, 21);
    top: 21.5%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200%;
}

#select-oak img {
    position: relative;
    left: -10vw;
    transform: scale(1.06);
    filter: blur(5px);
}

#select-oak img:hover {
    filter: none;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
```

It seemed like an unconventional approach so I wasn't surprised it didn't work, but since I am relatively new to CSS, JS, and JQuery, I'm curious as to what is stopping this from working just to help my understanding of working with JQuery and CSS. Here's the result. As you can see, it doesn't update until the last pass in the loop, even though the correct values are being printed out.

[image: Example]

So I have two questions:

1. Is this a problem with my code, or just something you can't do?
2. If updating styles like this is possible, is it a bad practice, and why?

Comment: Would flexbox not perhaps be better for this than grid to begin with? Then you should be able to achieve this kind of effect by simply manipulating the flex properties of the hovered item.

Comment: @04FS Yes it would, but this was made purely for my own practice, and since I like using grid for responsiveness on other projects I wanted to see if it was possible to make this method work. Mostly out of curiosity and for learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` loop is blocking the render process, because it is synchronous.

**I've come up with a way using CSS transitions, being agnostic of the number of child elements.**
It also handles the mouse leaving and even moving from one menu item to another.

```js
$('.selector-block > *').hover(function() {
  let frValues = Array($(this).siblings().length+1).fill('1fr');
  frValues[$(this).prevAll().length] = '2fr';
  $('.selector-block').css({
    'grid-template-columns': frValues.join(' ')
  });
}, function() {
  let frValues = Array($(this).siblings().length+1).fill('1fr');
  $('.selector-block').css({
    'grid-template-columns': frValues.join(' ')
  });
});
```

```css
.selector-block {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.selector-block > * {
  border: solid red 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selector-block"><div id="select-oak">select-oak</div><div>foobar</div><div>baz</div><div>bat</div></div>
```

<strike>You could do this with CSS only, no JavaScript, if the number of child elements is fixed, via the `:nth-child()` selector and `:hover()` as well, but this way, you can dynamically add elements to your menu any time.</strike> Actually, you couldn't, as you would need to trigger the parent's property animation from the hover of a child, which is not possible.

**Old answer:**

You're looking for [`window.requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). Here's a basic demonstration of how it would work. You'll have to tweak your values for a smoother transition and handle the mouse leaving the element of course.

```js
let start;
let elapsed = 0;
let rafHandle;

function hoverAnimation() {
  if (elapsed <= 1000) {
    elapsed = new Date().getTime() - start;
    let val = elapsed / 1000;

    $('.selector-block').css('grid-template-columns', `${1.0 + val}fr 1fr 1fr 1fr`);
    //console.log(1 + val);
    //console.log(elapsed);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      rafHandle = window.requestAnimationFrame(hoverAnimation);
    }, 1000/60); // about 60 FPS
  }
}

$('#select-oak').hover(function() {
  start = new Date().getTime();
  elapsed = 0;
  rafHandle = window.requestAnimationFrame(hoverAnimation);
}, function() {
  // handle mouse leave animation here instead
  window.cancelAnimationFrame(rafHandle);
  elapsed = Infinity;
  $('.selector-block').css('grid-template-columns', `1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr`);
});
```

```css
.selector-block {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selector-block"><div id="select-oak">select-oak</div><div>foobar</div><div>baz</div><div>bat</div></div>
```

Comment: Updated to include a basic example.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame()` was exactly what I was looking for, I had no idea it existed. Thanks a bunch for your help! Just wondering, is this a common practice?

Comment: Yes, it's used to update the DOM without blocking, whenever resources are free. I've come up with an even better way, using CSS transitions, being agnostic of the number of child elements. See the update to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Executing JavaScript blocks rendering the page, which only occurs after code execution returns to the event loop.

While changing style attributes may update the DOM and affect dynamic calculations of element positions and sizes, updating the screen remains deferred until the script finishes. This is why you only see the result of the last update.

**A1:** you can't affect page display inside a synchronous JavaScript loop.

**A2:** it's not bad practice because it can't be done :-)